# why print statement behaves in reverse order?

Tags: perl

In my perl progarm i have the following code:

```
@alpha=('toM','jERRy','mickeY','MARio');
print sort{$a cmp $b} @alpha,'  "***MIDDLE STRING***"  ';
```

here it prints the

> '  "***MIDDLE STRING***"  '

first and then the sorted @alpha list. Why it prints in reverse order, when

```
print "a","b";
```

prints

> ab

in correct order. I googled for help but it speaks about "reverse" function/method of perl but i don't use that function in my code. I found the answers irrelevant.

I guess it deals something with internal working of "print" function, using "stack" data structure, but I have no idea. Somebody help me out.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
print sort {$a cmp $b} @alpha,'  "***MIDDLE STRING***"  ';      #1
print sort {$a cmp $b} (@alpha,'  "***MIDDLE STRING***"  ');    #2

print (sort {$a cmp $b} @alpha), '  "***MIDDLE STRING***"  ';   #3
(print sort {$a cmp $b} @alpha), '  "***MIDDLE STRING***"  ';   #4

print ((sort {$a cmp $b} @alpha), '  "***MIDDLE STRING***"  '); #5

print sort {$a cmp $b} @alpha;                                  #6
print '  "***MIDDLE STRING***"  ';

print sort(@alpha), '  "***MIDDLE STRING***"  ';                #7
print sort({$a cmp $b} @alpha), '  "***MIDDLE STRING***"  ';    #8
```

#1 and #2 are equivalent: `sort` is operating on a list containing all of the elements of `@alpha` plus the string, thanks to Perl’s automatic flattening of lists. You might be tempted to add some parentheses around `sort` (#3), but that doesn’t help you either, because it’s interpreted as a list of two elements (#4): the result of calling `print`, and the string. Thus the string will not be printed, because it has nothing to do with `print`.

You could use an extra set of parentheses (#5) or split it up (#6), but knowing `sort {$a cmp $b} @alpha` is identical to `sort @alpha`, you can omit the block and the parentheses become straightforward (#7). And by the same rule, if you do need a comparison function, you can put both arguments to `sort` within parentheses, *not* separated by a comma (#8).

I also like to define subs for different kinds of sorting, to make the code simpler to read:

```
sub numerically { $a <=> $b }
sub backward { $b cmp $a }

print sort(numerically @array);    # Sort numerically ascending.
print sort(backward @array);       # Sort lexicographically descending.
```

Comment: Why not `print sort(@alpha), '***MIDDLE STRING***'`?

Comment: @TLP: I was just refraining from removing the block argument till I gave a reason for it. And `print sort(@a), "s"` is fine, but `print sort{$a cmp $b}(@a), "s"` has the same problem as the question. But I’ll edit to add that example.

Comment: Actually, that'd be `print sort({$a cmp $b} @a), "s"`. No problem.

Answer (score 7):

`'  "***MIDDLE STRING***"  '` is an argument to `sort`, so it's sorted along with the elements of `@alpha`.

If you want to print the sorted contents of `@alpha` followed by that string, you can do this:

```
print +(sort{$a cmp $b} @alpha), '  "***MIDDLE STRING***"  ';
```

Note that without the unary `+`, the parentheses apply to the `print` call, and the comma preceding the string literal is a comma operator, not a delimiter between arguments.  (Yes, this is an odd feature of the language.)

It's clearer to write it as two separate statements:

```
print sort {$a cmp $b} @alpha;
print '  "***MIDDLE STRING***"  ';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution to making sure arguments go where they are supposed to is to use the optional parentheses for the functions in question:

```
print sort(@alpha), '***MIDDLE STRING***';
```

This applies to a lot of situations, e.g.:

```
print join(':', @array), "\n";
@array = map(uc, @foo), @bar;
```

I think it makes it easy to see which arguments belong where, rather than wrapping whole statements in parentheses.